# Sobrescrever classes Bootstrap com arquivo CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Estou com uma dificuldade para sobrescrever algumas classes do Bootstrap utilizando um arquivo CSS que criei.
Estou utilizando o Bundle para fazer essas alterações:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles, bool premium =true)
{
    #region Default Web Site

   ..........

    #region Templates Layout

    if (premium)
    {
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Templates/premium").Include(
        "~/Templates/*.css"));
    }


    #endregion

    #endregion

}
```

Declarei o bundle no Layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/NoJScript" />
    </noscript>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @Styles.Render("~/Templates/premium")
</head>
<body>
```

Código arquivo CSS:

```
.container .navbar-default {
    background-color: #a6d209;
```

E mesmo assim o nav bar não altera a cor que inserir no arquivo externo.

[image: Projeto executando em Localhost]

O arquivo está vindo na ordem que inserir no bundle, está correto. Eles está vindo depois do bootstrap.css e site.css

[image: Carregamento do CSS externos]

Answer (score 1):

Tem que verificar a ordem que o CSS está executando. Porem, se fizer dessa forma:

```
background-color: #a6d209 !important;
```

Teu CSS ira prevalecer.

Comment: Obrigado, sabe me informar como eu verificar a ordem? Por que inserir o bundle nessa ordem, achava que seguia ordem que inserir o arquivo.

<code>
    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));

            if (premium)
            {
                bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Templates/premium").Include(
                "~/Templates/*.css"));
            }
</code>

Comment: No head. Se teu arquivo está incluindo antes ou depois do arquivo do bootstrap. Não esqueça de marcar essa respostas, caso ela tenha solucionado teu problema.

Comment: Postei a imagem acima e o arquivo está vindo por último seguindo a ordem que inserir no  bundle e mesmo assim não está alterando o nav-bar do bootstrap.

Comment: Verifique o resultado no browser. Normalmente vale as regras definidas por último. A não ser que o CSS anterior utilize "!important".

Comment: Não usa, por que se eu inserir o mesmo css no arquivo "site.css" ele funciona normalmente...mesmo sem o !important

Comment: O arquivo "site.css" está sendo incluído após o bootstrap no código fonte da página(não no que você escreveu, e sim no que foi fornecido para ao browser)? Se a resposta for sim, então não é necessário o "!important".

Comment: Sim está sendo incluído após bootstrap

<head>
      <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <link href="/Templates/premium-nav-bar.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

Comment: O teu arquivo de CSS deve vir por último. Depois de tudo. No seu caso.  Isso aqui `<link href="/Templates/premium-nav-bar.css" rel="stylesheet">` esta sobrescrevendo teu código css. Por isso não está funcionando sem você forçar. Mais uma vez: SEU CÓDIGO DEVE VIR POR ÚLTIMO.

Comment: Conseguir, valeu, problema era o nome do arquivo css que contém os "-", renomeie o arquivo e funcionou obrigado pela ajuda.